# inject stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: is it possible?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

```
var TM128_naver = new CS(csList.TM128_katech_3param);
var WGS84_google = new CS(csList.GOOGLE_WGS84);
// TM128_katech_3param(naver map) -> GOOGLE_WGS84 test
var Xe = 400000.
var Yn = 600000.
var p2 = new PT(Xe,Yn); //(X_east,Y_north)
cs_transform(TM128_naver, WGS84_google, p2);

document.write(p2.x);
document.write(p2.y);
```

i wonder var p2 data injecting possible by UIWebView

i used stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString but is doesn't work :(

how do i use p2 data in javascript

Comment: In future please take the time to format your code correctly using the editor controls. If you can't be bothered to spend time asking a question, why would you expect people to bother answering it?

Comment: sorry it's my first time question i'll find editor and edit ASAP

Answer (score 0):

When are you executing this code? The code is not self contained; `CS` must be being declared before this code is executed.

Your code should be ran in the `-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` webview delegate method to ensure that other code has been loaded.